# Magento 2 - Custom module file upload configuration and save in custom module table

Tags: magento2, import, custom

**File upload in Magento 2 store configuration**

```
<section id="custom_section" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="301" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
    <label>Custom</label>
    <tab>sales</tab>
    <resource>Magento_Sales::config_sales</resource>
    <group id="custom_group" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="6" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" >
        <label>Security</label>
        <field id="custom_file_upload" translate="label" type="Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\File" sortOrder="6" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" >
            <label>Upload custom file</label>
            <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\File</backend_model>
            <upload_dir config="system" scope_info="1">test</upload_dir>
        </field>
    </group>
</section>
```

This gives below upload option in Magento admin custom module configuration and the file is also getting uploaded at specified path.

[image]

- Just like we import `tablerates.csv` which also inserts data into `shipping_tablerate`, how do I make sure that the file content also gets inserted into custom table?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I got solution for this. So sharing here:

You have to extend backend model file in your custom module like below:

1. In system.xml, update code as below for input type="file"

```
 <field id="customfile" translate="label" type="Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\File" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Custom file</label>
                    <comment></comment>
      <backend_model>Vendor\Package\Model\Config\Backend\CustomFileType</backend_model>
                    <upload_dir>upload</upload_dir>
</field>
```

2. In your custom module, Create file **CustomFileType.php** at below place:

> Vendor\Package\Model\Config\Backend

3. Override **beforeSave** method in that file as below:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Package\Model\Config\Backend;


class CustomFileType extends \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\File
{



    public function beforeSave()
    {
        $value = $this->getValue();
        $file = $this->getFileData();
        if (!empty($file)) {


            /*** Here you can write your custom code to save data in custom table ***/

            $uploadDir = $this->_getUploadDir();
            try {
                /** @var Uploader $uploader */
                $uploader = $this->_uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $file]);
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions($this->_getAllowedExtensions());
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploader->addValidateCallback('size', $this, 'validateMaxSize');
                $result = $uploader->save($uploadDir);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('%1', $e->getMessage()));
            }

            $filename = $result['file'];
            if ($filename) {
                if ($this->_addWhetherScopeInfo()) {
                    $filename = $this->_prependScopeInfo($filename);
                }
                $this->setValue($filename);
            }
        } else {
            if (is_array($value) && !empty($value['delete'])) {
                $this->setValue('');
            } elseif (is_array($value) && !empty($value['value'])) {
                $this->setValue($value['value']);
            } else {
                $this->unsValue();
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }


}
?>
```